# Where to put images in Grails 2.4 framework

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I noticed that in Grails v2.4.4, the images, stylesheets, js files are all saved under

```
..pathOfProject/grails-app/assets
```

This seems to conform to the [Asset Pipeline Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline), but I am quite sure I have not installed this plugin. In older versions such as v2.1.0, I remember placing all my images or new CSS files in

```
..pathOfProject/web-app
```

but now I see this directories & subdirectories all empty.

What is the best practice where to put these assets (images, js, css) for the latest grails version (2.4.4)?

Also, why the change in directory location for these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the change of directories is because the asset pipeline plugin is included by default in Grails 2.4.0+ (See [What's new in 2.4](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew24)). Use the directories under `grails-app/assets` to store your images (and other assets).

The asset pipeline plugin [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/) has a wealth of information that will help you get the most out of using this plugin and follow the best practices for it's use.